# Changing background color of selected UITableViewCells in iOS5

Tags: uitableview, background, background-color, ios5.1, uiappearance

My app displays grouped static UITableViews in different screens. Is there anyway of using the appearance proxies

```
[UITableView appearance]
```

or

```
[UITableViewCell appearance]
```

to customise the background color for the selected cells? Basically I would need to modify

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor
```

for each cell in my app,but I cannot find the right property to be set in the proxy object.

BTW I have tried also the normal approach (being a group static table):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

}
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide a view to selectedBackgroundView. There isn't one already there. Try:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds] ;
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor] ;
```

Also, a better place to put this code (at least the first line) is in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when the cell is created. Otherwise you will be creating a new background view every time the cell is displayed.

Comment: -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: affects all cells.

Comment: what i meant was, selected background view portion will do change selected cell's color. however, cell itself deselects while you are dragging. additional note for you, it is good practice to put any kind of pre-visual effect in cell using `willDisplayCell` delegate method.